# How to use ifelse across multiple columns in a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have multiple columns in a data.table that I would like to apply an ifelse statement on. I could repeat the code for every column, but am wondering if there is a more elegant solution

For a given data table, I want to alter some numeric columns using the ifelse statement.

Here is the data:

```
dt = data.table(id = c(101, 102, 103, 104), one_cnt = c(0, 6, 4, 0), two_cnt = c(4, 0, 0, 2))

dt
```

If I wanted to do this manually, I could do this across all columns

```
dt$one_cnt = ifelse(dt$one_cnt == 0, 0, 2)
```

Instead, I'd like to select the following columns and apply the ifelse on each

```
colnames(dt)[grepl("cnt", colnames(dt))]
```

for one_cnt and two_cnt, a 0 value would end up with a 0. A non-zero value would take on a 1 value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `.SDcols` to specify selected columns.

```
library(data.table)
cols <- grep("cnt", colnames(dt), value = TRUE)
dt[, (cols) :=  lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x == 0, 0, 2)), .SDcols = cols]

dt
#    id one_cnt two_cnt
#1: 101       0       2
#2: 102       2       0
#3: 103       2       0
#4: 104       0       2
```

From your attempt you are replacing 0 values with 0 and changing non-zero value to 2 but in your description you mentioned that you want to change the non-zero value to 1, so I am not clear about your expected output. If you want to change it to 1, you can do

```
dt[, (cols) :=  lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(as.logical(x))), .SDcols = cols]
```